# Turn off Adaptive Card response confirmation for MS Teams bot app

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Adaptive cards for bots in MS Teams now appear to be displaying a confirmation of "your response was sent to the app" message when a button on the card is clicked.

Is there a way to turn this notification off?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, and cannot be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I can tell you most of my users do not like this functionality at all and they want a way to turn it off.

Comment: Could you please help by raising it on [Microsoft Uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Answer (score 2):

In a MS Teams if you have your message formatted as Adaptive Card you have different kind of buttons (Actions),

Some of them are resulting with "Your response was sent to the app" some of them not.

We had same issue and found out that if you are using type Action.Submit - it will show this notification, but if you use **Action.Execute**, it will not.

```
     ...
    {
      type: 'Action.Execute',
      title: 'My Button',
      data: {
        msteams: {
          type: 'task/submit',
        },
        somePayload: '<data>',
      },
    },
    ....
```

Hope it'll be helpful to someone stumbled upon the same issue.